# How to access Entity views via Javascript in Microsoft CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a custom page where I'm pulling entities via the ODATA rest url like this:

http:/[myCRMURL]/AccountSet?$filter=SomeColumn eq 'SomeValue'

I also have some Views declared under the entity in addition to the build in views:

- Account Advanced Find View
- Account Associated View
- Account Lookup View
- Active Accounts
- Inactive Accounts
- My CUSTOM FILTER

Is there a way via the ODATA rest API that I can pull the list of views for an entity? My google-foo is completely failing me today.

If so is there a way to apply one of those filters via the REST API?  Something like AccountSet?$viewId=[the GUID of the view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the views via the Rest API by hitting the `UserQuerySet` and the `SavedQuerySet`.  That will allow you to retrieve the information for the views like the columns, fetchXml, view name, etc.  However once you retrieve that view you will then either need to execute the fetchXml via the SOAP endpoint, or translate the filter criteria into the OData query yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm newer to CRM and had no idea those sets existed.